# Why do MediaWiki's Infoboxes use Lua?

Tags: mediawiki

I'm currently a newbie to MediaWiki administration, and I'm currently trying to wrap my head around Infoboxes.

Why do they use Lua instead of wikitext?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lua is a programming language.  See the [Wikipedia Lua page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Lua) for more information.

This allows the info boxes to be more dynamic.  The same info box can be shown on multiple pages and show slightly different content that is customized to the page that it is on.

Comment: Can you give me an idea of something Infoboxes do through Lua that can't be done in a standard template?

Comment: complex string manipulation, unit conversions, building tables or similar complicated HTML, fetching data from Wikidata, unit tests etc. You can just look at random Lua modules for more examples.